# In Domain Driven Design (DDD) How do you record and document a model

Tags: domain-driven-design

In Domain Driven Design how do you document key aspects of your model so that it can be communicated with your team and so that it can be developed over time?

By Key Aspects I mean:

ubiquitous language
  aggregate roots
  Entities / Value Object
  Invariants

Comment: Seriously? It's all stored in someones head and shared using word of mouth?

Comment: Yes. Languages tend to be spoken. The bandwidth of the communication is very important.

Comment: You might want to lookup some of the definitions in here: http://domainlanguage.com/ddd/patterns/DDD_Reference_2011-01-31.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the code.  And in conversations.  And on whiteboards, and documents, and models...

The key points are (1) ubiquity and (2) consistency.  So if a domain expert talks about "Assessing a Loan Application", you should have code that syntactically and semantically matches that concept. So you might have `LoanApplication.Assess()`.  You wouldn't have `ApplicationManager.QualifyApplication()` or similar.

So you would minimally record the language in the code.  You may also choose to record in documentation and/or diagrams.  You will also use on whiteboards and in discussions. But in all cases it's the same language.

hth.

Comment: So would you write up a "dictionary" for the language? I would imagine that when you have several domain experts they would not use the same words for things. On top of this you wouldn't have all your devs and domain experts in every meeting so how do you keep that consistency?

Comment: The idea of the ubiquitous language is that you develop a common language so that everyone *does* use a common vocabulary for the domain.  If domain experts are using different words for things, that's a problem they should try to solve.

Comment: Twisted: that can and does happen.  As @DonRoby says, part of the process is agreeing specifically what terms mean.  That requires discipline on all fronts; for Domain experts it means being more precise than is often the case.  For example, differentiating between 'types' and 'instances' of things: e.g. the book 'Domain Driven Design' and a specific copy of that book.  They are not the same thing. but in normal conversation both would often be referred to as simply 'the Domain Driven Design book'.  Being clear which you mean is part of developing that ubiquitous language.

Comment: So when you agree "specifically what a term means" do you not find that you have to write the agreed meaning up somewhere so that we maintain consistency and don't forget what was agreed (which sounds time consuming) or is just using it enough?

Comment: Bit of both.  I like having definitions written down personally.  A wiki can be a good way to do that since it encourages everyone to participate.  But the key thing is using the language consistently and constantly, then it becomes part of the project "dna".

Comment: Thanks sfinnie.  One last thing when you say "..and models"  is there a specific modelling approach for DDD or do teams use the "standard" psudo-uml and ad-hoc diagrams that we all know and love?

Comment: DDD doesn't prescribe a modelling approach.  The Domain Model is fundamental - but it's important to note the distinction between 'model' and 'diagram'.  In the DDD book, the 'model' is the code.  You can choose to do only that or to augment the code with some diagrams.  UML is probably the most popular diagram syntax, although it's not the only one (e.g. Dataflow diagrams, other ad-hoc).  You could even choose to use a graphical model (e.g. UML) as the definitive source (e.g. using an Executable UML approach).